# How to make web call in roar engine?

Tags: php

I am new to [Roar Engine](http://roarengine.com/). Can anybody tell me about the complete procedure for how to make web calls to Roar Engine via php script ?

Comment: From their site, their API is just REST - would a [question like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182505/making-a-rest-api-request-in-php) help?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly address your question but hopefully it makes things easier for you.

We've been hard at work building our new product: roar.io, virtual goods + mechanics.

It's a single JavaScript file that you can drop into your game that gives you instant access to a shop to sell virtual goods and actions that affect player state as well as pre-baked integrations with Facebook, Google+, Super Rewards, Applifier and Claritics (more to come).

We like to think of it as easy money for game devs. It shouldn't need any 'integration' for HTML5 games.

I'd love your feedback! http://admin.roar.io